# Wordpress Meta / Non-Meta Query 'OR' Clause

Tags: wordpress

We've written a custom Wordpress API and the API has parameter called 'id'.  The values that are passed into this parameter could be either Custom IDs defined in a custom field or (if that is empty) a Wordpress Post IDs.  In other query languages I could accomplish this several different ways (either two WHERE clauses connected with an OR statement or else with a custom field that is populated with data from either column).  I cannot, however, figure out how to do this in Wordpress.  I feel like it should be possible, but I can't find any example.

If I was searching for two values in a Meta Query or a Tax Query, I could use an OR statement, but I can't figure out how to do this between a Meta Query and a Non-Meta Query.

Is this possible and how would you do it?

Comment: So I've searched the internet for 3 hours straight... given I cannot find any information on whether this is possible (even though it is not an advanced action in other query languages) I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do.  I haven't tried anything other than research and I don't know if I am missing something or what...

Comment: We're going to try doing what we want with a 'posts_where' filter, but this seems like overkill.